# Response of completionHandler is nil

Tags: swift3, alamofire, completionhandler

I have function below which returns courses per user:

```
func CoursesPerUser(controler: UIViewController, completionHandler: @escaping (Result<[Course]>) -> Void){

    Alamofire.request(Constants.API.Users + UserId() + Constants.API.CoursesPerUser + Token(), encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in

        guard response.result.error == nil else {
            print(response.result.error!)
            completionHandler(.failure(response.result.error!))
            return
        }

        guard let json = response.result.value as? [[String: AnyObject]] else {
            print("Didn't get course objects as JSON from API")
            completionHandler(.failure(BackendError.objectSerialization(reason: "Did not get JSON array in response")))
            return
        }

        var courses:[Course] = []
        for element in json {
            if let courseResult = Course(json: element) {
                courses.append(courseResult)
            }
        }
        completionHandler(.success(courses))
    }
}
```

When I call the function response has value of nil.

```
NetworkManager.sharedInstance.CoursesPerUser(controler: controler) { response in

        print("Size of courses" + String(describing: response.value?.count))

}
```

I have printed each element in function CoursesPerUser and everything works fine. I wonder if I am not handling result in the good manner.

Comment: Please post your solution as the answer as someone else might encounter this issue and it will be more readable if your solution is in form of answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem. The solution is below.

```
func CoursesPerUser(completionHandler: @escaping ([Course]?, NSError?) -> ()){

    Alamofire.request(Constants.API.Users + UserId() + Constants.API.CoursesPerUser + Token(), encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in

        switch response.result {

        case .success :


            if let result: AnyObject = response.result.value as AnyObject? {

                if(response.response?.statusCode == 200){

                    var courses:[Course] = []

                    if let array = JSON(result).array {

                        for element in array {

                            if let course = Course(json: element) {

                                courses.append(course)

                            }

                        }
                    }

                    completionHandler(courses, nil)

                } else {

                    if let message = JSON(result)["message"].string {

                        print("Logg: " + message)

                    }
                }

            }

        case .failure(let error):

            completionHandler(nil, error as NSError?)
        }
    }
}



NetworkManager.sharedInstance.CoursesPerUser() { courses, error in

    if(error == nil) {

        print("Size of courses" + String(describing: courses.count))

    } else {

        print("Log: " + String(describing: error))

    }

}
```